# Get a queryset from a queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a queryset from `Picture.objects.filter(user_ID=user)`. The Picture model has "contest_ID" as a foreign key.

I'm looking to get a queryset of Contests which have Pictures, so from the queryset I already have, how do I pull a list of Contest objects?

Comment: How do your models look like? What is `user_ID`? Why do you not use the convenient way like `qs.filter(user__pk=user.pk)`?

Comment: @manch  try this:   picture_obj.contest_set.all()  you will get all contests related to this picture object.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta, that will work for individual objects, but not on a queryset.

Comment: @wobbily_col yeah! you are right. we can loop over and get all the Contest objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to follow the [reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
user_contests = Contest.objects.filter(picture__user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your models look something like this

```
class Contest(Model):
    ... something ...

class Picture(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    contest = ForeignKey(Contest)
    ... something ...
```

So, `Picture.objects.filter(user=user)` gives you pictures by a particular user (don't have to specify _id, filters operate on model objects just fine). And to get contests with pictures by a particular user you can do

```
pics_by_user = Picture.objects.filter(user=user)
contests_by_user = Contest.objects.filter(id__in=pics_by_user.values_list('contest', flat=True))
```

There might be an easier way though